# Using regex and vba, extracting parts of data

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet and within its contents it is formatted like -

Street Name, Street Number Street Direction(may not be present represented be an NSWE)

So it could look like John Doe Ave, 900 E or Jane Doe DR, 100

However, the people who used this spreadsheet put business names or other information that shouldn't be present

The part I'm stuck at is using regex patterns I'm not familiar with it and it confuses me

I have this variable

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "^(.+),\s(\d+)\s([NWSEnwse])"
```

So, I have this its working SLIGHTLY I wanted to know what changes I could make to this so it would include or exlude NWSEnwse, because right now it detects the address only when street direction is present

Comment: `However, the people who used this spreadsheet put business names or other information that shouldn't be present` Can I see few examples?

Comment: Use `?` to indicate that the previous item in the regex might or might not be there. See (this page on the optional quantifier)[http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html]

Comment: They will put buisnness names, so sometimes it can be  John Doe LLC with no address or it could be John Doe Ave - John Doe LLC or John Doe Ave (John Doe LLC)

Comment: I figured it out ^(.+),\s(\d+)(\s([NWSEnwse])|) adding a | solves my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex pattern to match it.

```
^(.+),\s+(\d+)(\s+[NWSEnwse])?
```

The `?` at the end signifies that that part is optional.
I also replaced `\s` with `\s+` to account for any extra spaces that might have crept in.